# CODE - UC SEG STATUS NOT ALLOWED Sabre error occurs when I try to Book fligth segment using Create Passenger Name Record API?

Tags: php, api, curl, sabre, sabredav

I am trying to create Passenger Name Record using Create Passenger Name Record API of Sabre. But When I pass information fetched from BargainFinderMax API to Passenger Name Record API, It gives the following error. It happens in some requests.

Please find below my Request Sample Flight segment part
`"OriginDestinationInformation":{
                        "FlightSegment":[
                           {
                              "Status":"NN",
                              "MarriageGrp":"O",
                              "FlightNumber":"206",
                              "NumberInParty":"2",
                              "OriginLocation":{
                                 "LocationCode":"JFK"
                              },
                              "ArrivalDateTime":"2018-09-15T22:10:00",
                              "MarketingAirline":{
                                 "Code":"EK",
                                 "FlightNumber":"206"
                              },
                              "ResBookDesigCode":"U",
                              "DepartureDateTime":"2018-09-14T22:20:00",
                              "DestinationLocation":{
                                 "LocationCode":"DXB"
                              }
                           },{
                              "Status":"NN",
                              "MarriageGrp":"I",
                              "FlightNumber":"604",
                              "NumberInParty":"2",
                              "OriginLocation":{
                                 "LocationCode":"DXB"
                              },
                              "ArrivalDateTime":"2018-09-16T05:30:00",
                              "MarketingAirline":{
                                 "Code":"EK",
                                 "FlightNumber":"604"
                              },
                              "ResBookDesigCode":"U",
                              "DepartureDateTime":"2018-09-16T02:30:00",
                              "DestinationLocation":{
                                 "LocationCode":"KHI"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }`

Below is the response with error that I receive from the API.

```
{"CreatePassengerNameRecordRS":{"ApplicationResults":{"status":"NotProcessed","Error":[{"type":"BusinessLogic","timeStamp":"2018-09-11T08:45:51.946-05:00","SystemSpecificResults":[{"Message":[{"code":"ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE","content":"Unable to perform air booking step"}]}]}],"Warning":[{"type":"Application","timeStamp":"2018-09-11T08:45:51.946-05:00","SystemSpecificResults":[{"Message":[{"code":"WARN.SP.PROVIDER_ERROR","content":"EnhancedAirBookRQ: CODE - UC SEG STATUS NOT ALLOWED-0003"}]}]}]}},"Links":[{"rel":"self","href":"https://api.test.sabre.com/v2.1.0/passenger/records?mode=create"},{"rel":"linkTemplate","href":"https://api.test.sabre.com//passenger/records?mode="}]}
```

could you please guide me why this happens. please also note that I am sending this request from PHP using CURL. In some cases booking is successfully completed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal, but the rate of getting is UC code should be less than **10%.** 
Possible reasons could be

- **Your PCC is blocked.** Which is not the case with you because you are not getting this code on all requests.
- The airline when you are booking becomes **unavailable** or the **seat is taken** before you confirm your PNR
- The issue also comes in some **coshare flights** where partnered airlines have some issues

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I contacted the Sabre support and got similar explanation.

Comment: Great! I got the answer from the Sabre support as well :)

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior and depends on the flights you use, at the moment of booking them they may not be available anymore. cURL and PHP do not affect this in any way. Are you obtaining this flight combination from BFM or an availability request?

Answer (score 0):

As this workflow is notorious unstable, i recommend you using the SOAP Enhanced Airbook + Passenger Details. I have not heared of anybody that is using create PNR in production yet.